# ValueError: x and y must be the same size In Python while creating KMeans Model

Tags: python, matplotlib, k-means

I'm building a Kmeans clustering model with a churn dataset and am getting an error that says ValueError: x and y must be the same size when trying to create cluster graph.

I'll post both my function and the graph code here in a sec, but in trying to narrow it down, I think it may have something to do with this line of code in the function:

```
x=kmeans.cluster_centers_[:,0]
                , y=kmeans.cluster_centers_[:,1]
```

Here's the full code

```
def Create_kmeans_cluster_graph(df_final, data, n_clusters, x_title, y_title, chart_title):
    """ Display K-means cluster based on data """
    
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=n_clusters # No of cluster in data
                    , random_state = random_state # Selecting same training data
                   ) 

    kmeans.fit(data)
    kmean_colors = [plotColor[c] for c in kmeans.labels_]


    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
    plt.scatter(x= x_title + '_norm'
                , y= y_title + '_norm'
                , data=data 
                , color=kmean_colors # color of data points
                , alpha=0.25 # transparancy of data points
               )

    plt.xlabel(x_title)
    plt.ylabel(y_title)

    plt.scatter(x=kmeans.cluster_centers_[:,0]
                , y=kmeans.cluster_centers_[:,1]
                , color='black'
                , marker='X' # Marker sign for data points
                , s=100 # marker size
               )
    
    plt.title(chart_title,fontsize=15)
    plt.show()
    
    return kmeans.fit_predict(df_final[df_final.Churn==1][[x_title+'_norm', y_title +'_norm']])



//Graph

df_final['Cluster'] = -1 # by default set Cluster to -1
df_final.iloc[(df_final.Churn==1),'Cluster'] = Create_kmeans_cluster_graph(df_final
                            ,df_final[df_final.Churn==1][['Tenure_norm','MonthlyCharge_norm']]
                            ,3
                           ,'Tenure'
                           ,'MonthlyCharges'
                           ,"Tenure vs Monthlycharges : Churn customer cluster")

df_final['Cluster'].unique()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get that error because of this line:

```
plt.scatter(x= x_title + '_norm'
                , y= y_title + '_norm'
                , data=data 
                , color=kmean_colors # color of data points
                , alpha=0.25 # transparancy of data points
               )
```

If you use `plt.scatter`, it does not take in `data=` as an argument, you can read [the help page](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html). You can either do:

```
plt.scatter(data[x_title + '_norm'],data[y_title + '_norm'],...)
```

Or you use the [plot.scatter method](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.scatter.html) on a pandas dataframe, which I did in a edited version of your function:

```
def Create_kmeans_cluster_graph(df_final, data, n_clusters, x_title, y_title, chart_title):
    plotColor = ['k','g','b']
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=n_clusters , random_state = random_state)

    kmeans.fit(data)
    kmean_colors = [plotColor[c] for c in kmeans.labels_]

    data.plot.scatter(x= x_title + '_norm', y= y_title + '_norm',
                      color=kmean_colors,alpha=0.25)

    plt.xlabel(x_title)
    plt.ylabel(y_title)

    plt.scatter(x=kmeans.cluster_centers_[:,0],y=kmeans.cluster_centers_[:,1],
                color='black',marker='X',s=100)
    
    return kmeans.labels_
```

On an example dataset, it works:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
random_state = 42

np.random.seed(42)

df_final = pd.DataFrame({'Tenure_norm':np.random.uniform(0,1,50),
                         'MonthlyCharge_norm':np.random.uniform(0,1,50),
                        'Churn':np.random.randint(0,3,50)})

Create_kmeans_cluster_graph(df_final
                            ,df_final[df_final.Churn==1][['Tenure_norm','MonthlyCharge_norm']]
                            ,3
                           ,'Tenure'
                           ,'MonthlyCharge'
                           ,"Tenure vs Monthlycharges : Churn customer cluster")
```

[image]